# jQuery clone losing some functionality?

Tags: jquery, clone, jqxwidgets

I am using jQuery `clone` to clone parts of a form and restore to their original state (saved in the clone) if the user decides to "cancel".

My clone code looks like this:

```
$(filterSec).find("select option:selected").attr("selected", true); // clone doesn't save user selections
savedFilterSec = filterSec.clone(true);
```

And the code to restore:

```
$('.openFilter').replaceWith(savedFilterSec);
```

This works for most of my form. The problem is that I have some [jqxListBoxes](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxlistbox/jquery-listbox-api.htm) that are restored to their original state when the user cancels, but no longer work - I can no longer select anything (or drag and drop, which I set up using [jqxdragdrop](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdragdrop/jquery-dragdrop-api.htm)). Is there some functionality that is not being cloned? How can I reactivate the list boxes after the "rollback"?

**Edit:**

This seems to be a problem with all jqxWidgets, not just the list box.

Comment: Do these `jqxListBoxes` have events bound to them? I'm guessing they do. Events bound to DOM elements are not carried over when using jQuery `.clone()` - http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Perhaps you need to call the constructor on the relevant elements again, after you restore the code? `$('.jqxListBoxClass').jqxListBox({...});`

Comment: @matthewpavkov - I tried that and it didn't help. I also tried calling `endUpdate` and `refresh`...